# Python - if given GMT Offset, and Given UTC - How to get the current time in a time zone?

Tags: python

I am am given the following:

```
The offset of the user's time from GMT in minutes.  For example, GMT+10 is
timezone_offset = 600.
```

I use pytz to get the current time in UTC:

```
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone
now_utc = datetime.now(timezone('UTC'))
```

How do I the get the users time?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `timedelta(hours=10)` or `timedelta(minutes=600)` to the datetime object containing the UTC time.

However, it would be a better idea to store the timezone instead of the offset and then use Python's timezone functions to convert the time.

Comment: so the uses time is now_utc + timedelta(minutes=600)?